# Create Custom Map functionality in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkmapview

[image: Image of map]

I want to create a sample map of any specific region in which a user can tap on any of the regions and the region colour will get changed to orange.

For this I have added some buttons on the top of the image but it does not provide accurate results.

Please share your reviews on this.

Comment: you can use UITapGestureRecognizer and then calculate which region was selected. You can get touch coordinates from gesture recognizer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773165/detecting-a-tap-on-a-cashapelayer-in-swift

Comment: Hello rmaddy, Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know how we will create the region with custom shapes as it is not a rectangle/square.

Comment: Use CAShapeLayer. Just draw shape and assign it to path property of this object and then I guess you can check if point is inside this shape by invoking method `hitTest` or use CGPathContainsPoint with CGPath assigned to layer.

Comment: Hello Andy, If you could share some code or links for the same then it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Ok I'll add answer to this question later tonight or tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CAShapeLayer. In this example I check if touch location is inside particular layer and then if touch location is inside path of this layer.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  private let step = 50
  private lazy var rectSize = CGSize(width: step, height: step)
  private struct MapSize { let width: Int; let height: Int }
  private let mapCanvas = UIView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    generateMap(withSize: MapSize(width: 6, height: 6))

    view.addSubview(mapCanvas)
    mapCanvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapCanvas.leadingAnchor),
      view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapCanvas.trailingAnchor),
      view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapCanvas.topAnchor, constant: -200),
      mapCanvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
      ])

  }

  private func generateMap(withSize size: MapSize) {
    for x in 0..<size.width {
      for y in 0..<size.height {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x * step, y: y * step), size: rectSize)
        layer.path = createPath().cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mapCanvas.layer.addSublayer(layer)
      }
    }
  }

  private func createPath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let rectangle = UIBezierPath()
    rectangle.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    rectangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: step))
    rectangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: step, y: step))
    rectangle.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: step, y: 0))
    rectangle.close()
    return rectangle
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first, let sublayers = mapCanvas.layer.sublayers else { return }
    let touchLocaltion = touch.location(in: mapCanvas)
    for sublayer in sublayers {
      guard let shape = sublayer as? CAShapeLayer,
        let path = shape.path,
        shape.hitTest(touchLocaltion) != nil else { continue }
      let locationInsideRect = mapCanvas.layer.convert(touchLocaltion, to: shape)
      if path.contains(locationInsideRect) {
        if shape.fillColor == UIColor.red.cgColor {
          shape.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        } else {
          shape.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPD: Logic for checking if touch was on particular shape is inside `touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` method

[image: Demo]

Comment: Many thanks Andy. Awesome Man. It works exactly like as it is showing in above image. Really you did a great work :)

Comment: Now I just have last query, Instead of rectangle how we will create the custom shapes.

Comment: You can draw any shape using UIBezierPath. Then you can assign it to UIShapeLayer and locate on screen.

Comment: For drawing shapes you can use PaintCode and then export swift code from it

Comment: Andy, How we will identify which region has been tapped as we have many region's ?