# iOS CALayer tap recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, calayer

I have a line like this:
[image]

Which is drawn on a CAShapeLayer using the following code:

```
class LineView: UIView {

    let rwPath = UIBezierPath()
    let rwLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let rwColor = UIColor(red: 11/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 14/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    func setData() {
        rwPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0))
        for i in 1...200 {
            rwPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: i + 50, y: i + 50))
        }

        setUpRWLayer()
        layer.addSublayer(rwLayer)
    }

    private func setUpRWLayer() {
        rwLayer.path = rwPath.cgPath
        rwLayer.fillColor = nil
        rwLayer.lineCap = .butt
        rwLayer.lineDashPattern = nil
        rwLayer.lineDashPhase = 0.0
        rwLayer.lineJoin = .miter
        rwLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
        rwLayer.miterLimit = 10.0
        rwLayer.strokeColor = rwColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

I've been trying for a while to detect a tap on that line. I've tried using UITapGestureRecognizer and overriding touchesBegin:withEvent func, but nothing seems to work so I've come to ask here.

Hit test code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let point = touches.first?.location(in: self)

    if let hitLayer = self.layer.hitTest(point!) as? CAShapeLayer {
        if (hitLayer.path?.contains(point!))! {
            print("Touched")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions listed here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29773165/3151675 Make sure user interaction is enabled.

Comment: Yes I have tried, user interaction is enabled. That one didn't work. I can print out the CGPoint which I click but when I try to do a hitTest it always fails, no matter where I clicked.

Comment: Please include the hit testing code in the question as well.

Comment: @TamásSengel I included hit test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create outline for it as it will work accurately for click event on CAShape layer

Try this code and let me know if you face any issue

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first

    guard let point = touch?.location(in: self.view) else { return }
    guard let sublayers = self.view.layer.sublayers else { return }
    var caShapelayers : [CAShapeLayer] = []
    for layer in sublayers {
        if layer is CAShapeLayer{
            caShapelayers.append(layer as! CAShapeLayer)
        }
    }

    for layer in caShapelayers {
        if let path = layer.path{
            let outline = path.copy(strokingWithWidth: 13, lineCap: .square, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0)

            let iscontain = outline.contains(point)
            if iscontain  {
                //    print(layer)
                Singleton.sharedSingleton.showAlert(controller: self, message: "You want to delete this link?", title: "Are you sure?") { (buttonPressed) in
                    if (buttonPressed == "YES"){
                        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```